# How could docker container can visit another intranet host?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, intranet

I run a docker container C on host A, Now I need C to visit another **intranet** host B. Now I can not `ping` B's IP success in C. What should I do ?

PS: C could `ping` any internet ip Success.

PS：`net.ipv4.ip_forward` is set to open.

I'm a docker beginner, Hope you can show me the detail config for learning. Thanks~~~

Comment: Are you able to ping it from A?

Comment: All of A, B, C could `ping` internet succesfully.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Can A ping B or not?